# Function as a variable with generics in it?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, functional-programming, foundation

I am trying to create a variable of a generic function type:

```
import Foundation

typealias Processor<T:Decodable> = (T.Type, URL) -> Promise<T>

struct Service {
    let processor: Processor

    func getAPI1() -> Promise<TypedResponse1> {
        let url = ...
        return processor(TypedResponse1.self, url)
    }
    
    func getAPI2(params: [String]) -> Promise<TypedResponse2> {
        let url = ...
        return processor(TypedResponse2.self, url)
    }

}
```

Compiling gives me an error:

```
Reference to generic type 'Processor' requires arguments in <...>
```

However, I don't want to specialize the variable since it kinda beats the purpose of having it and will be more difficult to test.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Your `Service` would need to be generic like `struct Service<T: Decodable> { let processor: Processor<T> ... }`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Are you sure it makes sense to have one processor for multiple APIs with different types? Surely they'd each need a different processor

Comment: @Alexander not really since I am passing the URL and type, it's all that's required for me to make specialised calls.

Comment: It is important to understand that different specialised instances of a generic are not co-variant.  You cannot use `Array<Int>` and `Array<String>` interchangeably.  I.e. How would you declare a variable that could hold `[Int]` or `[String]`?  You can't (Unless you resort to `Any`). Similarly you can't declare a variable that can hold any specialisation of `Processor`.  You need to tell the compiler if it is a `Processor<Type1>` or a `Processor<Type2>` etc

Comment: You could create a `Processor` object that implemented a generic, function `get<T: Decodeable>(_ url: URL) -> Promise<T>` and then call it `let promise: Promise<Int> = Processor().get(someUrl)`